# RxJS deliver all messages in correct sequence

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am currently struggling with a scenario where I have 3 subscribers of an RxJS Subject, and one of the subscribers (the second subscriber (B) ) adds a messages to the subject when it receives a message from the subject.

What this causes is, that the third subscriber (C) receives all messages after the message that B has sent and also in the wrong order.

This is my code:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

var mystream = new Subject<any>();

// first observer 
mystream.asObservable().subscribe(msg => console.log('A: ', msg));

// second observer which also adds a message to the subject
mystream.asObservable().subscribe(msg => {
  console.log('B: ', msg);

  if(msg === 'Initial message') {
    mystream.next('Message from B');
  }
});

// third observer who receives the messages as the last one and in incorrect oder
mystream.asObservable().subscribe(msg => console.log('C: ', msg));

// start the whole process
mystream.next('Initial message');
```

This currently gives me the following result:

```
A:  Initial message
B:  Initial message
A:  Message from B
B:  Message from B
C:  Message from B
C:  Initial message
```

How can I achieve the following result?

```
A:  Initial message
B:  Initial message
C:  Initial message
A:  Message from B
B:  Message from B
C:  Message from B
```

Comment: that's observable's default behavior which is it can be sync and async depending on how you execute the code. if your intention is to run some initialization, you can run in a `startWith` operator `mystream.pipe(startWith('Initial message'))`

Comment: @FanCheung actually this is a very simplified example. I have much more subscribers and much more messages, which leads to the problem that some subscribers get all the messages (in the example from B) in reverse order and only after B stops sending it's messages. How would I execute the code for the observable to to fit this behaviour?

Comment: We usually don't have to worry about the order in event listening case ( subject ), in most cases the app will be initialized with subscribers/listener attached. Then the event firing should be async, i.e when sync initialization code has already executed. If your subject.next() is a sync task, then i think it should probably belong somewhere else in your code pipeline.

Comment: The only concern i see in your example is probably this line `mystream.next('Message from B')` and yes you can use a `setTimeout` to make it right. or using `timer(0).pipe(tap(()=> mystream.next(...)` and the answer below is quite neat as a legitimate solution

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it using the `asyncScheduler` in your consumable observable to emit each notification in a different tick.

It'd be something like this:

```
var publisher = new Subject<any>();
var myStream = publisher.pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler)); // <----

// first observer
myStream.subscribe((msg) => console.log('A: ', msg));

// second observer which also adds a message to the subject
myStream.subscribe((msg) => {
  console.log('B: ', msg);

  if (msg === 'Initial message') {
    publisher.next('Message from B');
  }
});

// third observer who receives the messages as the last one and in incorrect oder
myStream.subscribe((msg) => console.log('C: ', msg));

// start the whole process
publisher.next('Initial message');
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your idea! That indeed works, but isn't that somehow a "prettier" version of doing a setTimeout(() => publisher.next('Message from B'), 1) ? e.g. waiting for the event loop to clear and then insert the next message.

Comment: @LukasLeitner Yes indeed, it has the same effect.